# How much does block.one have in funding that support itself?

Tags: block.one, funding

Supposedly block.one raised 4 billion in Ether.

- Did they sell all the ether? How much is left?
- How much usd funding do they have to support themselves?
- How is block.one allocating their funds?

Answer (score 1):

> Did they sell all the ether? How much is left?

Yes, all ether was transferred from the [token sale contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd0a6e6c54dbc68db5db3a091b171a77407ff7ccf), some of which ended up on Bitfinex.

> How much usd funding do they have to support themselves?
>
> How is block.one allocating their funds?

Block.one is not a publicly traded company, so most of this information is not public. However, you can follow the [block.one news page](https://block.one/news/) for announcements relating their funding and capital deployment.